# How To Change redirect when using [Authorize]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorize

I understand that to change the url [Authorize] takes you to. You have to edit this line in the web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

What if I have two sign in pages and I want to redirect people from one controller to url /f/signin and people from another controller to /s/signin?

Comment: At the cost of an extra redirection, the easiest way I can think of solving this would be to replace the `loginUrl` with an action that decides which category the user is in and then redirects them to the appropriate signin action.

Comment: You'll need to have `returnUrl` as a string parameter to your redirecting action (i.e. the action pointed to by `loginUrl`). The initial authentication redirect will supply this value in the query string. You can reverse engineer it to discover where the user came from.

Comment: How do I pass a string parameter to the web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could point `loginUrl` to an action that redirects the user appropriately.

It would look something like this:

```
public class MySpecialLoginController:Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string returnUrl)
    {
        if(returnUrl.EndsWith("/foo")) //dirty. you could do better...
        {
            return RedirectToAction("signin","f");
        }
        //etc
    }
}
```

and, assuming default routing, `loginUrl` would have the value `"~/MySpecialLogin"`

Comment: when the aspnet auth decides that the user doesn't have access for a page (let's say it's `foo/bar`), it issues a redirect to the `loginUrl` with a query-string something like `?returnUrl=foo%2fbar`, so that after you login, you can be returned to the place from which you came. In short, it's populated automatically.

Comment: hmm seems like it should work but it isn't? I made an action in the f controller called Redirector(string ReturnUrl), I put a break point in there but it is not entering even though this url is showing up /f/Redirector?ReturnUrl=%2fF%2fprofileperson%3fid%3d21&id=21

Comment: never mind didn't work because I was using httppost. Works great! Thx